# stock changed name looking for cost basis

Tags: taxes, stocks

Looking for stock prices from 2000 to 2010 for Yahoo stock which is now Altaba (AABA).  Believe it may be defunk now.  Yahoo finance doesn't show historical prices for delisted or the old name for a stock.  Need to find cost basis for taxes

Comment: How did you buy/hold this stock? Every broker I used during that decade reported cost basis on my statements at least quarterly, even though reporting of basis to IRS didn't become mandatory until 2012-plus.